# EDSDK How to get Av property during LiveView

Tags: c++, edsdk, canon-sdk

*I'm having trouble with getting kEdsPropID_Av after opening session with the camera.*

Eventually I would like to get Av property before each video is taken but at the moment I can't even get Av property straight after opening session. (I'm able to get properties like ZoomPossition During LiveView etc. but no luck with Av).

I've also tried getting Av while button is Half pressed (during LiveView mode) using command kEdsCameraCommand_PressShutterButton but also no luck so I went back to absolutely basic code but it still doesn't work and I'm getting AvValue = 0.
Any help would be much appreciated.

***My basic code:***

```
// Open session with camera
Error = OpenSession(CamRef);
if (Error == EDS_ERR_OK)
{
std::cout << "session open" << std::endl;
EdsUInt32 Av;
Av = getAv();
std::cout << "Aperture: " << Av << std::endl;
else{std::cout<<"EDSDK Error: " << Error << std::endl;}
```

***getAv function:***

```
EdsUInt32 getAv(){
EdsDataType dataType;
EdsUInt32 dataSize;
EdsUInt32 AvValue;
Error = EdsGetPropertySize(CamRef, kEdsPropID_Av, 0, &dataType, &dataSize);
if (Error == EDS_ERR_OK)
{
    Error = EdsGetPropertyData(CamRef, kEdsPropID_Av, 0, dataSize, &AvValue);
}
return AvValue; }
```

Comment: The code looks correct. What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry pressed enter to early..   Oddly I'm not getting any error. I'm just getting 0 value and it should be decimal value 48. I can read current aperture on the screen of my camera  i.e. 5.6 which in hex is 0x30 and in decimal should be 48 but still when I try to read it using SDK and code above I'm getting 0. My first question is: do I have to set focus on something in order to get Av or I can get Av value every time I run getAv() function? Do I have to turn on LiveView in order to get Av or set camera to some kind of different mode before reading Av?

Comment: ah, you probably are not in manual mode. 0 either means either Auto or None (e.g. no lens or manual lens). As far as I know you can't get Av/Tv/ISO when in an automatic mode.

Comment: I've noticed one thing: If I start LiveView manualy on my camera and run application after that (which opens session and read Av) I'm getting correct value. But it seams that this value "is locked" even though aperture on the screen of my camera is changing the aperture which I see in the console is not changing. (I've put getAv() function inside while(1) loop). Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm in Autofocus mode if this is what you have on mind. Program set on the dial of the camera is Personal, but I've tried Automatic and Manual as well and it's all the same. Still getting 0.

Comment: no, autofocus is something different. I mean the exposure mode. e.g Program, Auto, Manual, etc. If you are in Manual (or Av priority) you should get a correct value. If not, what do you get when calling EdsGetPropertyDesc with kEdsPropID_Av?

Comment: AvDesc.form 0, access 3, numElements 17, propDesc[0] 45, propDesc[1] 48... There is huge array with elements, could you specify what would you like to see?

Comment: it's a list of possible values you can set/get for Av. If the length would be zero, you wouldn't be able to set any value. and presumably, you'd only get zero as a result. What happens if you set and then get the Av value? (all in manual, of course)

Comment: Ok, it seams that I can set and read Av when the LiveView is switched off, camera dial is set on Av and the camera is in Picture mode but once I switch to Video mode with dial set to AV I can no longer set or read Av. What I need is to get information about current light condition before taking video. Is there any chance to do so? Any other API? If not is there any chance to switch off LiveView while being in Video mode to check the aperture? I've tried set property ~kEdsEvfOutputDevice_PC but I'm getting Error 129 Device Busy..

Comment: I can' test it right now, but it should work in video mode as well. as long as you are in manual or aperture priority mode. Getting the lighting condition is not possible as far as I know (been searching for that as well). What's possible is reading the histogram of the live view image (make sure it doesn't adjust itself but shows exposure simulation). You can't switch off the live view when in video mode, it has to run in this mode.

Comment: I'll keep trying then. In the mean time you have intrigued me with this histogram idea. I'm not sure how can I propagate histogram data to the table I've created. Could you please comment on this? My code:  `EdsUInt32 HisY[255];
   Error = EdsGetPropertyData(evfImage, kEdsPropID_Evf_HistogramY, 0, sizeof(HisY), &HisY);`  I'm also not sure how can I analyse these data. Shell I simply look for max value in the middle of the x axis of the histogram in order to get approximate light condition or there is more to it? Thank you for your help..

Comment: First, the array should have a size of 256. The other line looks fine. About analyzing, not quite. I suggest you read up on histograms first. Basically a histogram shows the amount of pixels of a certain value. Black on the left (index 0), then getting brighter until white on the right side (index 255). Normally a photo has values distributed all over. You need to balance it between black and white.

Comment: Could you indicate what camera model? Also, the things that you do seem to get are via the evfImage itself, but did you try obtaining other properties like Tv, ISO etc AFTER initial startup? If not, do you have a proper property event handler set (EdsSetPropertyEventHandler) for receiving value changes in the camera ? Just checking, also because you mention a while(1) loop which has the potential to block a thread and prevent events from coming in.